# Is it possible to combine 2 http responses into one in Angular?

Tags: angular, http, service

I have `Angular 6` app and external service `api` that returns maximum 50 records per request. But in some cases I need to get 100 records.

For example the following request will give me first 50 records:

```
www.example.com/records/?count=50
```

The following next 50:

```
www.example.com/records/?count=50&lastID=FAKEID
```

Is there any best practice to send 2 HTTP requests in one angular service method but return both response data together?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use forkJoin of rxjs

```
import { forkJoin } from "rxjs/observable/forkJoin"; // Maybe import from 'rxjs' directly (based on the version)

...

public multipleRequestMethod() {
    const firstCall = this.http.get('www.example.com/records/?count=50');

    const secondCall = this.http.get('www.example.com/records/?count=50&lastID=FAKEID');

    return forkJoin(firstCall, secondCall).pipe(
        map([firstResponse, secondResponse] => [...firstResponse, ...secondResponse])
    )
}
```

More info: [Here](https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-multiple-http-requests-with-rxjs)

If you want to use response from first request then you need to use flatMap/switchMap

```
import { map, flatMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

...

public multipleRequestMethod() {
    return this.http.get('www.example.com/records/?count=50').pipe(
        flatMap(firstResult => {
            return this.http.get('www.example.com/records/?count=50&lastID=' + firstResult[firstResult.length - 1].id).pipe(
                map(secondResult => [firstResult, secondResult])
            );
        })
    );
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I thought you used `merge()`. I need more coffee this morning.

Comment: We can never have enough coffee :)

Comment: `lastId` is contained by first response, so I need to use value from first response as parameter for second request